# enable input fields if radio buttons is checked with jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have this radio buttons in html code:

```
<span><input type="radio" value="false" name="item[shipping]" id="item_shipping_false" checked="checked"><label for="item_shipping_false" class="collection_radio_buttons">No</label></span>

<span><input type="radio" value="true" name="item[shipping]" id="item_shipping_true"><label for="item_shipping_true" class="collection_radio_buttons">Yes</label></span>
```

and I have 1 disabled field like:

```
<input id="item_shipping_cost" class="currency optional" type="text" size="30" name="item[shipping_cost]" disabled="disabled">
```

I want that if an user click in option **Yes** in radio buttons, remove the html attribute`disabled="disabled"` to this last input field, and if user click in option **No** in radio buttons add the attribute`disabled="disabled"` to this last input field

**How can I do it with jquery?**

thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
   $('#item_shipping_true').click(function()
{
  $('#item_shipping_cost').removeAttr("disabled");
});

$('#item_shipping_false').click(function()
{
  $('#item_shipping_cost').attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

see demo in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cp7GT/)

Answer (score 6):

```
$('input[name="item[shipping]"]').on('click', function() {
   if ($(this).val() === 'true') {
      $('#item_shipping_cost').removeProp("disabled");
   }
   else {
      $('#item_shipping_cost').prop("disabled", "disabled");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You would like to use JavaScript like this:

```
   $('#item_shipping_false').change(function() {
      $('#item_shipping_cost').prop('disabled', false);
    });
    $('#item_shipping_true').change(function() {
      $('#item_shipping_cost').prop('disabled', true);
    });
```

​
This is complete [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrGNr/2/) of your case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/Zha8W/1/)

. I think this will help you

Comment: the input not disable when click no