# how to enable a textarea depending on which radio button was clicked?

Tags: php

[this the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aug9f.jpg)

[screen capture of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMiXQ.jpg)

Comment: This the answer http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/4c/cc/a9/4ccca95556d19603da07dbe96595a02d.jpg

Comment: do not post a screenshot of your code, post your code instead. and write a more thorough question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498036/enable-input-fields-if-radio-buttons-is-checked-with-jquery check this post, I had place the code on, but people keep voting me down so I will just leave it here

Comment: @Eli how can I apply the link  tutorial, to my code?

Comment: You have to give an id to your input and use Jquery to access that input. So I guess is the one with the other text. so you can make jQuery remove the disable attribute when is selected and add it if it is deselected.

Comment: @Eli still dont get it I added another picture of my database

Answer (score 1):

You could do try using JQuery, if you can put a unique ID on each of the radio buttons and the textarea, you can try something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#radio-button-id").click(function(){
        $("#textarea-id").prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
</script>
```

but of course replacing "radio-button-id" and "textarea-id" with actual ID's and importing JQuery in your head tag like this:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Copy and past that head tag on the top of your code, then make ID's for your radio buttons and textarea, and lastly copy and paste the script tag to the bottom of your code.

Comment: it worked! but for all button I only need the text area to be enabled when the last button is chosen which is the OTHERS button, I uploaded another pic of my table. thanks man!

Comment: No problem, make sure to upvote my answer with the green check mark

Comment: but how can I do this? I have 8 radio button, I need the 8th radio button to be enabled when its selected? everytime I choose a radio button the text area is enabled.

Comment: give them unique ids, try using the loop to echo a different id for each radio button.

Comment: @n0000b You are kind of taking a mile here. You need to do some research on this, people shouldn't have to do everything for you. Show some effort.